# Why is my match row function not being entered?

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have a userform that is pulling in data from a worksheet into the userform fields. I have a function that matches the row of that employee if the employee number in userform is found in column F.

It used to work but now it doesn't even enter the function to determine if that employee exists in the data.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim wb As Workbook:  Set wb = Workbooks.Open("J:\HRIS Team\Analytics\Headcount Tracking File.xlsx")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim lString As String, lArray() As String
    lString = cmbEmployee.Value
    lArray = Split(lString, " - ")
    Dim recRow As Range
    If optEmployeeName.Value = True And optEmployeeID.Value <> True Then
        Set recRow = MatchRow(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                          lArray(1))
    Else
        Set recRow = MatchRow(ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion, _
                          lArray(0))
    End If
    If recRow Is Nothing Then MsgBox "Employee not found"
    With recRow.EntireRow
        Me.cmbFunction.Value = .Cells(1).Value
        Me.cmbHRBP.Value = .Cells(3).Value
        Me.cmbRequestType.Value = .Cells(4).Value
        Me.cmbMovementType.Value = .Cells(7).Value
        Me.txtEffectiveDate.Value = .Cells(8).Value

Function MatchRow(tablerange As Range, lArray) As Range
    Dim rw As Range
    Dim lString_2 As String, lArray_2() As String
    lString_2 = cmbEmployee.Value
    lArray_2 = Split(lString_2, " - ")
    For Each rw In tablerange.Rows
        If optEmployeeName.Value = True Then
            If CStr(rw.Cells(6).Value) = Trim(lArray_2(1)) Then
                Set MatchRow = rw
                Exit Function
            End If
        ElseIf optEmployeeID.Value = True Then
            If CStr(rw.Cells(6).Value) = Trim(lArray_2(0)) Then
                Set MatchRow = rw
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next rw
End Function
```

I hover over to make sure it's getting the employee ID correctly from the lArray, and its there. I can't figure out the reasoning behind why it wouldn't even attempt to enter the matchrow function. Any ideas?

Comment: First step, get rid of that `On Error Resume Next`.

Comment: Just removed it, but no errors are occurring. Keep skipping over the  function and showing "Employee not found" even though they are in the worksheet.

Comment: Liberal use of `Debug.Print` should be helpful to debug further.

Comment: Yes the debug.print shows the current region as accurate `$A$1:$AZ$2`

Comment: row 2 is the only entry outside of the headers, so this shows that current region is accurate. the procedure doesnt even skip over the first set row line... it just highlights that while stepping through and goes straight to the else and then end if parts

Comment: Then add some `Debug.Print` statements inside the `MatchRow` function to see what values you're comparing together.

Comment: how can I add and further assess within the function if the sub procedure won't even enter it?

Comment: @BigBen so here is whats happening. The user enters the correct option buttons and the if statement shows that they are true, so it steps into the first `set` line in that if statement. it highlights it while im stepping through, meaning that it should enter the function, but it isn't

Comment: Right within `MatchRow`, put `Debug.Print "test"` or some other line that you are *sure* will get executed.

Comment: @BigBen I put a debug.print string test in the matchrow function but it wont reach it because this is what happens: Hits the `if optemployee....` and then hits `set recRow = matchrow(ws.range("A1").currentregion, lArray(1))` portion and then goes straight to `end if` because it doesn't enter the function

Comment: The code *has* to execute `MatchRow` in either the first or second part of the `If...Else...End If` though. Put a `Debug.Print` inside both parts to see which is being executed. And please ensure that you don't have `On Error Resume Next` still.

Comment: It's not though, I am actually stepping through line by line and it never enters the function within that if statement

Comment: Then you must have `On Error Resume Next` still. Code doesn't skip an `If...Else...End If`.

Comment: Could it just be a matter of my file being corrupted or something?